# How to disable suggestions in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, privacy, notifications

I have disabled "Get tips, tricks and suggestions while using Windows" and also disabled "Show me the Windows welcome experience..." in notification settings:

[image: Notification settings]

Yet, I have just received the following "Tip" on how to "improve" my Windows experience:

[image: Bored with your background? Notification]

How do I get rid of **all** those annoying notifications?

Comment: Something’s broken anyway, because Windows does not display the App name but the technical package name instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scroll down the *Notifications & actions* until you get to *Get notifications from these senders* and set *Suggested* to *Off*.

[image]